# wx.FileDialog open single file

Tags: wxpython

I want to force single file selection in wx.FileDialog. According to the doc not adding wx.MULTIPLE style will do. I have tried all combinations of style and none worked ! any idea ?

```
app = wx.App(0)
dlg = wx.FileDialog(None, message="Browse", style = wx.OPEN)
dlg.ShowModal()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Your example works fine for me (ie, I can not select multiple unless I add in wx.FD_MULTIPLE).  I'm running wxPython version 3.0.0.0 on OSX 10.9.2

Comment: it does ! this is really odd i don't know why i can select multiple files on my OSX 10.6.8 and wx version 2.8.10.1